# Are there any deep RL algorithms that work well on finite MDPs and non-trivial terminal rewards?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, markov-decision-process, algorithm-request, reward-functions

I notice that most Deep Reinforcement Learning (DRL) works focus on Markov Decision Process (MDP) with an infinite time horizon.

Are there any algorithms that work well on finite MDP and non-trivial terminal reward?

My definition of non-trivial terminal reward is that the reward function at the terminal time is different from the one at non-terminal timestamps. Many environments or games fall into this category. For example, many games are on $[0, T]$, the total reward is the summation of the accumulated reward plus the final bonus.